# Azure devops -- ensure local files match repository branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, filesystems, repository, directory

**Azure-devops -- ensure local files match repository branch**

How does one ensure using Azure dev-ops that the local files match the repository branch?

In my system, "old" versions of the files turn up like a 'bad penny' and frankly I am not sure why.

Is there a simple command one can run that guarantees this?

Certainly, entirely removing the local repository will do this, and Azure Devops detects this and loads all objects during a "clone" but surely there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using a self-hosted agent, otherwise you get a fresh virtual machine for every build on a Microsoft-hosted agent.

If the objective is to validate you match the repository branch, the best way is to just start by cleaning your sources.  The build pipeline makes it trivial by giving you an option on the Get sources step to specify the Clean options.

Comment: Does such a 'clean' remove all objects from the local version of the repository?

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't happen with a Git repo. But you could always add a command line step and run `git clean -dxf` against your repo. That will remove any files and folders not present in the branch you have checked out.

Comment: I wish it didn't happen but it does.  Sometimes I have to delete the entire solution to get just one object correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that avoiding operations like "sync" after cloning to a new branch actually **helps**.  With Azure Devops, it seems the phrase **"less is more"** is appropriate.  Also, sometimes one does just have to remove the local directories contents and re-clone the entire project, sadly.  The above answers may help, but I have not personally verified them, as our group does things in a different way.